# Broadcast Receiver not being called when JobIntentService is triggered

Tags: android, kotlin, service, broadcast

I am developing a sample app where my goal is to display a notification but initially, just for testing purposes I'm playing an alarm sound when Screen goes ON twice via 4 pressed in the power button. I also intend to run a Service even if the app is totally closed that's why I put the broadcast receiver inside the service.

Before when I implemented this using Service, the app seems to be working fine except for Oreo and above. I found out regarding the execution limit for background, so I updated my code by using Job Intent Service. I just noticed that my broadcast receiver is not being called though it gets registered in the JobIntentService class. I tried playing the alarm sound just on the service (broadcast receiver excluded), and the alarm goes playing, meaning that my Service is functioning properly. I was just wandering why the broadcast receiver is not getting triggered?

This is my code for this:

MainActivity :

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var receiver: SampleReceiver
private val actionCheck = "action_check"

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    receiver = SampleReceiver()

    btnStart.setOnClickListener {
        SampleJobIntentService.enqueueWork(
            applicationContext,
            Intent().setAction(actionCheck)
        )
    }
  } 
}
```

JobIntentService Class:

```
class SampleJobIntentService : JobIntentService() {

   private lateinit var receiver: SampleReceiver
   private val actionCheck = "action_check"

   companion object {
       fun enqueueWork(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
           enqueueWork(context, SampleJobIntentService::class.java, 123, intent)
       }
   }

   override fun onHandleWork(intent: Intent) {
       Log.v("Service", "Service is running")
       receiver = SampleReceiver()

       when (intent.action) {
           actionCheck -> {
               IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON).also { filter ->
                   this.registerReceiver(receiver, filter)
               }
           }
       }
   }

   override fun onDestroy() {
       unregisterReceiver(receiver)
       super.onDestroy()
       Log.v("Receiver", "Receiver is now unregistered...")
   }
}
```

Receiver class:

```
class SampleReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

   private lateinit var player: MediaPlayer
   private var pressedCounts = 0

   override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
       when (intent?.action) {
           Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON -> {
               pressedCounts =+ 1

               if (pressedCounts == 2) {
                   player.start()
               }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.example.samplereceiver">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <service
        android:name=".SampleJobIntentService"
        android:exported="false"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```